# HDMI in to MacBook Pro via Thunderbolt?

Tags: hdmi

Got an old DSLR that output HDMI. Got a MBP M1. Got a USBC hub with HDMI port.

Can I output from the DSLR into the hub and and transfer it and capture inside the MBP via USB-C port?

Answer (score 0):

The MBP's HDMI port is only an output. So no, you won't be able to capture it that way. It requires special equipment to capture through HDMI (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091NX27S8) one for example).

What is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: I wast to use use the DLSR as a webcam. Thanks.